# Error installing ember-cli-mocha

Tags: ember.js, mocha.js, bower

I'm trying to setup an EmberJS project using ember-cli. I want to be able to use Mocha/Chai instead of the default qunit, but I am getting an error at the first step on installing ember-cli-mocha.

I create the new ember project with `ember new my-project` and then from within the project folder I run `ember install ember-cli-mocha`, selecting Yes to overwrite the tests/test-helper.js.

In the output, immediately following the `Installed browser packages via Bower.` message I see:

`Package ember-cli/ember-cli-test-loader=ember-cli/ember-cli-test-loader not found`

I can't find any information on this directly. I've tried installing the various packages themselves, before the ember-cli-mocha package via npm and bower, but I always get that message when installing ember-cli-mocha through ember-cli.

Anyone else have experience with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of ember-cli?

Comment: @Gaurav I just used "npm install -g ember-cli", but it looks like it's version 1.13.6.

Comment: @randall, I created new ember application and followed the same procedure. It's working for me. Can you once again check it? Once you create the project, clear the npm and bower cache using the command `npm cache clean` and `bower cache clean` and install ember-cli-mocha. Let me know if it's works